# Heroku - Can't connect to local MySQL server

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, heroku

I have deployed my project containing

- Django
- Rest-framework
- Reactjs

to **Heroku** using [this medium post](https://medium.com/@nicholaskajoh/deploy-your-react-django-app-on-heroku-335af9dab8a3) as reference. Now, I have my code in `deploy-heroku` branch so I did:

```
git push heroku deploy-heroku:master
```

Now, the build was successful but the deployment got failed.

Here's the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 236, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 86, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 332, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 57, in _run_checks
    issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/database.py", line 10, in check_database_backends
    issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 9, in check
    issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 13, in _check_sql_mode
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 255, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 232, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 236, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 86, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

Where do that change that database configurations. I thought that heroku would automatically do this!

---

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'redditdb',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'USER':'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root'
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your settings?

Comment: Update the post

Comment: I wanted to see your `DATABASES` configuration specifically.

Comment: updated it again

Comment: You can't use your local DB on Heroku. If you don't mind I can write an answer on how you can use Postgresql on Heroku.

Comment: I am aware that I can't use Local database but I wasn't sure on what to replace it with! Please do specify usage og postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the changes you have to make in order to use postgres on heroku.

You have to install two python packages

```
 pip install psycopg2   # postgres adapter for python
 pip install dj_database_url
```

Remember to update this in your `requirements.txt`

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Finally in your **settings.py**, `import dj_database_url` and update your `DATABASES` settings as follows

```
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

Now deploy your app to heroku. Heroku will automatically add a postgresql addon for you.

Comment: Seems that my webapp is now deployed but there is an error in `heroku logs`. `app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found`

Comment: Have you added a `Procfile` in your root directory? If yes, can you show its contents?

Comment: I didn't have `gunicorn` in `requirements.txt` so that was the problem !

Comment: We had to change the database settings? Or only add these two lines in settings.py @Josewails