# Error on deploying Django app to Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

Hello i built my first Django app and i tried to make it live using heroku.
My app works fine locally. When i deployed it on heroku i get this error: "Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details."

I am really new to this. I dont know where to look for logs.
I tried [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/09/how-to-deploy-django-applications-on-heroku.html) tutorial to deploy the app.
My code on [github](https://github.com/thathana1521/django_eudokia).

Any ideas?

```
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at your code on Github. These are the mistakes you have made

1. You should rename `Procfile.txt` to `Procfile`
2. You also have to change your `DATABASES` settings in your `settings.py`. You can have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51286264/heroku-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server/51289008#51289008).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I followed the instructions but i am making something wrong with the databases settings and i get some errors. I edited the post. Please check the databases settings.

Comment: `DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)` should come after the DATABASES settings. You are actually updating the key of  `default` with a new value.